# How to proceed when a bountied question should be closed

Tags: discussion

Right now, there are two bountied questions in DSSE

- [Chain Function in Backprograpagation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/74328/chain-function-in-backpropagation): which is in need for clarification and
- ['TabularLIME' is not defined Azure DataBricks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/tabularlime-is-not-defined-azure-databricks): which is off-topic

The later includes an answer (which I flagged as non-answer) pointing it should be asked at StackOverflow and saying he had the same problem.

How should I proceed in these cases since I can't cast a close vote?

Comment: Thanks for flagging. I migrated the second question to SO (see @Glorfindel's answer) . I would leave the first question open to give the OP the opportunity to revise the question without having to reapply the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [flag these posts for ♦ moderator attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27103/295232). (Posting a Meta question like this one works too, but may create too much noise if it happens too often.) If they agree with you, they will cancel the bounty and close the question.